# Not Getting the Result I Need With the "Object Offset Array Option"

Tags: modifiers

I'm attempting to make a revolver cylinder following this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0ZISNcC6kM&t=262s.

The problem is occurring when I change the array modifier to object offset rather than relative offset. They should be of the same scale and be in the same position, but instead they're scaling down and moving toward the center. This method worked for me previously on the same project, but I decided to restart because I realized the cylinder was in the shape of an octagon instead of a hexagon.

If anyone can give some help It would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select RhinoCylinder Apply Scale and Rotate in 60 deg ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the scale of your *RhinoCylinder* object so that it's 1:1:1, rotate it 60° on Y (this is what he's doing with his empty at 4:10):

[image]